# Stop playing live stream mp3 while other plays?

Tags: ios, avaudioplayer, avaudiosession

I'm currently making a live stream music app, and i've got all the buttons to work and play sounds from them.

However, if one sound is playing, when i press another button, rather than stopping the original sound, it just plays over it, please help me how to fix this? HELP PLEASE !

Many thanks

```
- (IBAction)Play1:(id)sender {

    NSString *stream = @".mp3"
    ;

    NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:stream];

    NSURLRequest *urlrequest = [NSURLRequest requestWithURL: url];

    [Webview1 loadRequest:urlrequest];
    AVAudioPlayer *audioPlayer = [[AVAudioPlayer alloc] initWithContentsOfURL:url error:nil];

    [[AVAudioSession sharedInstance] setCategory:AVAudioSessionCategoryPlayback error:nil];

    [[AVAudioSession sharedInstance] setActive: YES error: nil];

    [[UIApplication sharedApplication] beginReceivingRemoteControlEvents];

    [audioPlayer play];

    [[UIApplication sharedApplication] beginReceivingRemoteControlEvents];


}
```

Answer (score 1):

create boolean value and set is true when stream playing.after that when you want to play another stream control your bool value , if it is true, first stop audioPlayer and  change audioplayer contentUrl with new url that you play.that's all

```
@property (nonatomic, assign, getter=isPlaying) BOOL playing; 

//first set playing NO , after that  

- (void)playAnotherStream:(NSURL *)streamUrl
{
    if (isPlaying) {
        [self.audioPlayer stop];
        self.playing = NO;
    }
    [self.player setContentURL:streamUrl];
    [self. audioPlayer play];
    self.playing = YES;
}
```

Comment: Thanks very much, sorry I am new to objective-C, should I add this to each stream-play? thanks